# MS Access VBA Writing to a table from a form

Tags: mysql, forms, vba, ms-access, subform

- I have a form (**Purchase Orders**) and a sub-form in it
  (**Purchase Order Details**). The Main form contains **Number of the
  PO** (text box), **Supplier** (combo-box), **Employee** (combo-box),
  **Status** (combo-box) which contains 2 records (New and Done) and a **date** box (when the PO was created). The Sub-form (datasheet) contains **Product** (combo-box), **Quantity** and a **Price** field.
- What I want to do is to add a button on the main form which will do
  next.
- When the button is pressed a VBA code should be executed and do next.
  Take data from the Main form (Number of the PO, Status and the date)
  and the Sub-form (Product, Quantity and Price) and put all that into
  a table (StockMovements).

I managed to do that with the next code:

```
Private Sub cmdOrder_Click()
Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO StockMovement (ID_Product, Status, Quantity, ID_PurchaseOrder) VALUES (" & _
               Me.frmPurchaseOrderDetails_Subform.Form!comboboxProduct & ", '" & _
               Me!txtStatus & "', " & _
               Me.frmPurchaseOrderDetails_Subform.Form!txtQuantity & ", " & _
               Me!txtID_PurchaseOrder & ");"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

However, there are 2 problems:

1. As you can see I didnt add the date field because I get an error,
   cant remember which one it was exactly but I think 2075;
2. The code works without the date, but only adds one Product to the
   table, the first one. And in a Purchase Order there are usually more
   than one products.

Because Im totally new in VBA, I would kindly ask you to treat me like a newbie and explain more detailed, if possible. 
(Fixed the code, forgot to change the language. I mean I pasted the wrong one, now its the right one but still not working of course :))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) If you only have a problem with one specific field, I would check whats special with that one. Probably the input is formatted as a string and the field as Date/Time. In that case try to use the CDate()-Function. I could imagine, that a .Value at the end could solve the problem, too.

```
Dim datDate as Date

datDate = CDate(Me!txtDate.Value)
```

2) That your code inserts only one row is absoluterly correct. Remember that e.g. *Me!txtStatus.Value* is a textbox that contains only one single piece of data. The rows of data are saved in a table and depending on the row you have selected with a main-form (= one row), the corresponding value is shown in the textbox.

```
INSERT INTO table (field1,field2) VALUES (value1,value2)
```

An INSERT INTO inserts one row every time it's executed. So the SQL in the code you have mentioned needs to be repeated. You could do so using loops.

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = ""

 For Each Item In Group
    strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO table (field1,field2) VALUES (value1,value2)"
 Next
```

In my opinion, copying data that way is absolutely annoying with VBA. You need to create recordsets, modify and merge them. I would try to solve as much as possible with Access Non-VBA-Solutions.

My question to you: Did you think about linking the form (and sub-form) directly to the table(s)?

Comment: I'm on my phone now and need se sleep, so will test the code when I wake up. How to link them exactly? The form and subform is created from existing tables and queries, isn't that a link? Or I can link them further to a third table/s? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `code
Private Sub cmdOrder_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = ""
For Each Item In Group
    strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO StockMovement (ID_Product, Status, Quantity, ID_PurchaseOrder) VALUES (" & Me.frmPurchaseOrderDetails_Subform.Form!comboboxProduct & ", '" & Me!txtStatus & "', " & Me.PurchaseOrderDetails_Subform.Form!txtQuantity & ", " & Me!txtID_PurchaseOrder & ");"
    Next
    
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
Me.Requery
    
End Sub
code`
I get a runtime error "13 ", Type mismatch.
When I go to debug it makes the "For Each Item In Group" yellow.

Answer (score 0):

The date can be inserted this way:

```
"INSERT INTO StockMovement ([DateField]) " & _
"VALUES (#" & Format(Me!DateField.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```

That said, your code *will* insert one record only. To insert multiple records you need a select query or - much faster - use *DAO* to open the target table as a recordset and then, as source, loop the *RecordsetClone* of your subform and copy the records to the target table one by one.

Comment: The thing is I have like 0 experience in VBA :/
Do you maybe have an example for that? About the date, I decided to leave it out and to set the dates default value to =Now() in the table, so it always put the date when the record was added to the table.

Comment: I don't have such code right at hand, sorry. Not difficult, though, neither "smart". Use `=Date()`, not `=Now()` if you wish to record the date with no time.